# MS SQL Tracking Status with High Volume Transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, architecture

I have a system, with multiple application servers that pick up jobs and process them. Each job has a set of 10-20 child records and each of those child records have 5-400 child records. All of this resides in Three MS SQL Tables with foreign key relationships.

While these jobs run in the application servers, almost real time status is needed. Its a business requirement. So the status is kept in same three MS SQL tables as above.

So while these jobs run it works ok up until a point. Then it degrades especially when jobs with more child records run. The problem is they are all fighting to update the Status on the same three tables and there are lots of updates.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to keep the real time status, but reduce the load to the MS SQL DB. Here are the options I was considering:
   1. Break the status details into separate tables, one for each of the three tables above. 
   2. Chunk the updates to the SQL DB
   3. Writing status to file and have the real time status retrieved via a web service or something.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you will need to do some `Profiling` also when you are running particular Select's / UpDates.. are you Locking.. or using `with no lock` for example.. do you have an experienced `DBA` who can look at your `Execution Plan` and see where the deficiencies are happening..?

Comment: I've looked at profiling in Visual Studios and its the Entity Framework / SQL calls. I've also traced / profiled the SQL DB while these transactions were processing and there can be 1000's of calls in a short amount of time.

Comment: Getting a DBA to analyze it is a good suggestion. I don't have one, but am considering contracting one for this purpose.

Comment: there are a lot of free tools that you can use online for instance do some googling on how to optimize and or track down performance issues in My Sql.. perhaps you can save your money and the only thing it will cost you is the time to google and research / try out recommended best practices etc...